# Is possible to pack a library with a framework in Xcode?

Tags: ios, macos, frameworks, ios8, xcode6

So I am trying to use the new framework target in `Xcode 6` and running into a issue were my framework is referring to a third party library. When I build I get that the file in the library cannot be found in my framework. Is there a way to pack them together in the framework? The third party library is already add as a linked binary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe so. That's how Cocoapods work yeah?

You add a line in the Podfile, then do a pod install, it installs the library, downloads any dependencies and includes the frameworks for you.

How you make a pod is beyond me :)

Comment: Well a cocoa pod works a little differently than a framework.